# Why didn't Clu use Sam's disc?

Tags: tron-legacy

Clu initially captures Sam, but for some reason allows him to play another game (lightcycle). In that game with the help of the Iso he is able to escape.

Why couldn't Clu just use Sam's disc to escape the Grid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sam is a user, but not the creator of the grid, so his knowledge is not extended as Kevin's. An Identity Disc contains all that the owner knows:

> You will receive an Identity Disc. Everything you do or learn will be imprinted on this disc. If you lose your disc or fail to follow commands, you will be subject to immediate deresolution.

Kevin is the creator of the second grid - his disk contains everything about the grid. But there is more on that disk. From the [tron wikia](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Kevin_Flynn%27s_Identity_Disc)

> Kevin Flynn's Identity Disc is a unique Identity Disc. Like other identity discs, Flynn's disc operates as a weapon if the need arises, although it has a more valuable function programmed into it by Flynn himself. **It is reputed to be a "master key" of sorts, and provides the only means by which a program might potentially escape the Tron system.** As the disc of a user it also stores data of a far more complex being than that of an ordinary program.

---

Also note that the first thing Clu does when he meets Sam is examine his disk:

> Clu: Disc.
>   [Holds out his hand to the guard behind Sam, which hands over Sam's disc]
>   Clu: Let's have a look...
>   [the disc displays all of Sam's memories up to that moment]
>   Clu: Got it. **Hm. I expected more...**

So, maybe he was hoping for a way to escape using Sam's disk, but he didn't find what he was looking for.

Comment: Good point at the end there